# Pry-rails appears to be corrupting my terminal, how can I fix this issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, zombie-process, pry-rails

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue. I have noticed for a while, whilst using standard pry with Ruby, that occasionally pry will appear to become stuck in a loop, requiring me to kill the terminal and reopen it. This was moderately annoying but not that bad since I could just reopen my terminal and everything would be fine...

Well, I have recently started working with rails and now, whenever my pry-rails hangs up and I kill the terminal, when I reopen my terminal, the terminal screen is totally blank. It will allow input but my path is gone and commands seem to do nothing.

Has anyone else had this issue with pry or pry-rails?

It was annoying enough having pry keep hanging up on me for no reason.

P.s. what I mean when I say my pry-rails is stuck in a loop is, whenever its output of code is fairly long...say... 30 lines or more, the pry terminal will appear to stop on a new line that says (END). It allows no more command inputs and wont accept any text input. I can keep hitting return but this will result in the output of the previously printed code over and over again. Which necessitates me killing the terminal. And now with this strange terminal corruption issues, i need to restart my mac in order to start using my terminal again.

Comment: `END` is a [keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) in ruby so this might have something to do with the issue.

Comment: I figured it out :facepalm: I had to hit q to escape the text that pry was printing out. Although I am still not sure why killing my terminal whilst it was in this state was resulting in a zombie process.